# Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell XPS 15 desktop lags

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 20.04, dell, xps

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell XPS 15:

```
i7-9750H
16GB
15.6" 4K UHD (3840 x 2160) OLED
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650
```

But I have lags on scrolling, feel like lost FPS, also video lags (tested on YouTube)
Not sure how to explain, system just not feel smooth.
Nvidia driver installed

```
~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
  x11
~$ prime-select query
  nvidia
```

Output for lshw

```
~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:180 memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:178 memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

```
~$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
~$ lspci -nn | grep '\[03'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) [8086:3e9b]
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] [10de:1f91] (rev a1)
```

Also `nvidia-smi` output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.100      Driver Version: 440.100      CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1650    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   58C    P5     5W /  N/A |   1253MiB /  3914MiB |      2%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1174      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           133MiB |
|    0      1764      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           280MiB |
|    0      2019      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         278MiB |
|    0      2789      G   ...AAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAA= --shared-files   547MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed! I have extension `indicator-multiload`, to show CPU, RAM and disk usage in toolbar. After disable this extension freezes gone. So if any one have same issue chech system load indicators extensions, base on my fast google this problemcan can also be with `system-monitor` extension, but not sure.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same issue, and I really couldn't find a way to fix it. I also encountered the exact same problem on basically any other ubuntu based system. The fix you mentioned sadly didn't work for me, those extensions weren't installed.

What I did was to move from Ubuntu to Manjaro, there the comparability with nvidia seems to be a lot better. Doesn't really fix or solve the issue but it's better than nothing.